# Oracle how to remove extra message in the select output file

Tags: oracle

run1.sql

```
SET ECHO OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET HEADING OFF;
SET LINESIZE 300;
select 'update compartment set tenant_name='''||name||''' where tenant_id='''||customer_id||''';' from customer;
```

excute command

```
sqlplus64 username/password@database  @/opt/token/run1.sql
```

result:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Apr 13 05:38:07 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


update compartment set tenant_name='abc' where tenant_id='101
1';
```

How to eliminate the below info and just list query result

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Apr 13 05:38:07 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

I tried "set temout off". But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a MS Windows example, based on Scott's sample `dept` table.

If you created a .sql file (`p.sql` for me):

```
SET ECHO OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET HEADING OFF;
SET LINESIZE 100;
spool p.txt
select * From dept;
spool off
```

and an operating system .bat file (`p.bat` for me):

```
sqlplus scott/tiger @p.sql
```

and - at the operating system command prompt call the **batch** file (not directly `sqlplus` with desired .sql script!), this is the outcome:

```
c:\Temp>p

c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger @p.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Tra 14 10:09:23 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
SQL>
```

But, the resulting spooled file (`p.txt`) looks like this:

```
10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK                                                                  
20 RESEARCH       DALLAS                                                                    
30 SALES          CHICAGO                                                                   
40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

So, nothing but data. I suggest you do the same.